# Cache build output and dependencies for custom CodeBuildStep

Tags: node.js, caching, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

We have a CDK Pipeline that at Synth step runs these commands

```
commands: ['npm ci', 'npx aws-cdk synth']
```

which install dependencies and build CloudFormation template.

Later on we add a custom CodeBuildStep that we want to reuse these  dependencies and the created template. What is the best way to do this? We tried caching but apparently doing something wrong. The source is visible in that custom CodeBuildStep but dependencies have to be installed again the synth has to be run again.

Answer (score 1):

You can output the template as an artifact and reuse it in the next steps.
Have a look at: [cdk codebuild artifacts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html#artifacts)

For reusing the dependencies, have a look at caching. It will save you time on reinstalling them: [cdk codebuild caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html#caching)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try CodeBuild caching, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. Are there any examples of consecutive build steps actually using data cached in previous steps?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the caching is meant for the same step but in the next build, I don't think I have an example of using the cached data in a consecutive step. In that case you should maybe pass the build as an artifact and skip building it a second time or cach the data in both steps the first time and use the caches in consecutive builds.